# ReactJs How to Delete state item by one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props

For example, if i add 10 of the same item to one cart how do i reduce it to 9.

```
this.state = {
   cart = {}
}
this.props.cart[key]
//tshirt: 10
```

Thanks.

Comment: you need to give more details.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to decrement, so what you can do something like this

`this.setState({tshirt: this.state.tshirt - 1})`

Answer (score 0):

first `this.state` and `this.props` are different, so looking at your code `this.props.cart === undefined`. unless there are parts of your code am not seeing.
That said `this.state.cart` is just like any other js object so assuming 'key' is the property name i.e `this.state.cart['shirt-10'] = {...propsOfShirt10 } you can just use`delete` using the key.

`delete this.state.cart['shirt10']`

Comment: just a side, and honestly none of my business, if you're new to js, pls don't start with react. learn the basics. with the new features your can go pretty far on just js .

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Sorry if it seemed like too noob question. The answer was, as always stupid and under my nose the whole time. Thanks for answering, your answers were helpful.

```
cart[key] = cart[key] - 1;
    if (cart[key] < 0){
        cart[key] === 0;
    }
    else{
    this.setState({cart})}
```